# Apply colour to datacell if certain value

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, foreach, styles

I want to loop through my datagrid, and if a row has a certain value (for example the value 3, this value is dynamic so can change, but for now lets say 3), change the background colour of the cell to green. The datagrid is populated by binding it to a datatable.

Is this possible?

See datagrid and c# below

```
 <DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="300" Width="900"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="40">
            <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        </DataGrid>
```

c# to create datatable

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("myDS");
            DataTable numbersTable = new DataTable("Numbers");
            numbersTable.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(Int32));
            for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++)
            {
                numbersTable.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            dataSet.Tables.Add(numbersTable);
            grid.DataContext = numbersTable.DefaultView;
```

P.s. very very very new to c# so dont assume Ill know what youre talking about. Forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Style Triggers in the style of an ItemTemplate.

Edit: full DataTemplate implementation

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I have not given you a fully functional code. You need to create a valid ItemTemplate and use a style inside it. See edit for example

Comment: Also, where has this random text block come from

Comment: You have put this in the DataGrid.ItemTemplate block? The textblock is an example of datatemplate. If you want to have a custom behaviour inside your cells, you need to override to default template with your own. I have put a textblock in mine, you can choose something else.

Comment: i just copied and pasted it.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
row.Cells[index].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: huh? You're assuming i know the coordinates of the cell? dont you put coordinates where you put index?